# Maintaining multiple Linux distros - boot and grub partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-partition

Here is my GParted view of `/dev/sda`

[image]

The unallocated blocks were once another Ubuntu distribution - I will resize my other partitions to consume them soon. `/dev/sda2` holds my Debian installation's root directory - which I installed first on a clean disk. The Debian installation created the `/dev/sda1` partition as a boot partition and a swap partition (which I deleted at some point). `dev/sda5` holds my Ubuntu root directory. I installed the two Ubuntu distributions by creating custom partitions, but to be honest I didn't really know what I was doing, I just messed with it till it worked.

#### Side questions

What is `/dev/sda7` for, and what does it do that `/dev/sda1` doesn't do? Could I combine the two together?

Also, everything is working and the two distros are booting fine. I just want to know where to go from here - should I change the partition layout to make it neater and more future proof in case I needed to add more Linux distros?

### Main question

If I added another Linux distro, how would I proceed? What partitions should I create and how should I organise them? (I don't want to share a `/home` partition). Do I need a separate `bios_grub` partition for each distro?

Comment: Your sda1 is the ESP or efi system partition. That is not the same as an Ubuntu /boot partition and you normally should not create a /boot partition for standard desktop installs. Full drive LVM or with encryption may need a separate /boot partition and some servers may also. Normal bios_grub partitions for BIOS boot must be unformatted and only need to be 1 or 2MB. Best to remove bios_grub flag on sda7 with gparted. It then can be a data partition or another install.

Answer (score 1):

The `bios_grub` partition is needed for enabling Legacy BIOS booting in GPT/UEFI setups. If you're booting with UEFI, which I, for the sake of simplicity, assume you do, you won't need it at all.

You can use the existent SWAP partition for all installed Linux systems, as they can't be booted simultaneously.

If you don't want a shared `/home`, the only thing you need to do is to create a root partition for the new system in the unallocated space on installation time (i.e. set its mount point to `/`) and format it as EXT4. As you are asking on AskUbuntu, I assume you'll be installing Ubuntu next. Ubuntu will automatically use existing swap partitions. If you install an OS that doesn't use it automatically, you can afterwards tell it to use the swap partition by adding the following to your `/etc/fstab` in the new system:

```
UUID=<uuid of /dev/sda6>    none    swap    sw  0   0
```

You can get the UUID with `sudo blkid`. To apply the new fstab, run `sudo swapon /dev/sda6`.

The boot loader for the new installation will have to go into `/dev/sda1`, the EFI partition. The newly installed GRUB should recognize the other installations. If not, run `sudo update-grub` after first boot.